# (Dartlang) How can I detect the selected item in the listview

Tags: dart, rikulo

**rikulo.org** has great example for list-view at
[**http://rikulo.org/resource/js/examples/index-list.html**](http://rikulo.org/resource/js/examples/index-list.html)

In this example, how can I detect the selected items in the list?
For example, how do I know '**Row 5**' is selected if I **click** or **touch** on '**Row 5**' ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can listen to onClick events for each list item by

   item.on.click.add((ViewEvent event) {
       // do whatever you want, handle selection, add/remove CSS class, etc
   });
2. Or add a checkbox within the list item, and listen to its onCheck event.

Note that Rikulo is under rapid development now and will add more construction. There will be a model driven list view that handles selection.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
document.onClick.listen((MouseEvent e){
   TableRowElement row = e.toElement;
   print(row.text);
 });
```

You can change document to : query("#table"), queryAll("tr"),ect